# BigQuery SQL join on multiple columns, but if both are unmatched, it should add a 0 row

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to do a join like the following:

Given table 1:

```
+-----------+------+-------+
| date      | name | count |
+-----------+------+-------+
| 1.1.2020. | A    | 5     |
+-----------+------+-------+
| 1.1.2020. | B    | 2     |
+-----------+------+-------+
| 1.1.2020. | C    | 3     |
+-----------+------+-------+
```

and table 2:

```
+-----------+------+-------+
| date      | name | count |
+-----------+------+-------+
| 1.1.2020. | B    | 1     |
+-----------+------+-------+
| 1.1.2020. | C    | 4     |
+-----------+------+-------+
| 1.1.2020. | D    | 6     |
+-----------+------+-------+
```

I want to join them by both date and name, but if name isn't in one of the tables, the final table should still have it, with count 0.

The resulting table would be

```
+-----------+------+---------+---------+
| date      | name | count_1 | count_2 |
+-----------+------+---------+---------+
| 1.1.2020. | A    | 5       | 0       |
+-----------+------+---------+---------+
| 1.1.2020. | B    | 2       | 1       |
+-----------+------+---------+---------+
| 1.1.2020. | C    | 3       | 4       |
+-----------+------+---------+---------+
| 1.1.2020. | D    | 0       | 6       |
+-----------+------+---------+---------+
```

Whichever join type I try, it only matches only those rows for which name is in both tables, so I would only get these two rows here

```
+-----------+------+---------+---------+
| date      | name | count_1 | count_2 |
+-----------+------+---------+---------+
| 1.1.2020. | B    | 2       | 1       |
+-----------+------+---------+---------+
| 1.1.2020. | C    | 3       | 4       |
+-----------+------+---------+---------+
```

This is one of the queries I tried, but also left join, right join, etc.

```
select * from 
    table_1 full outer join table_2 using(date, name)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you over simplified your example? Are you testing this with different data? Do you have a WHERE clause? Have you tested this EXACT example (exactly the same data, exactly the same query)?

Answer (score 2):

Consider below approach

```
select date, name, 
  sum(if(col = 'count_1', count, 0)) count_1,
  sum(if(col = 'count_2', count, 0)) count_2
from (
  select *, 'count_1' col from table_1 union all 
  select *, 'count_2' from table_2 
)
group by date, name
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider also yet another approach - less verbose with use of [PIVOT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#pivot_operator) operator

```
select *
from (
  select *, 'count_1' col from table_1 union all 
  select *, 'count_2' from table_2 
)
pivot (sum(count) for col in ('count_1', 'count_2'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You query should work, but I would phrase it as:

```
select date, name, coalesce(t1.count, 0) as count_1,
       coalesce(t2.count, 0) as count_2
from table_1 t1 full outer join
     table_2 t2
     using (date, name);
```

This returns the additional counts as `0` rather than `NULL`.

Comment: It still returns rows only for names which are found in both tables..

Comment: @nexx . . . That is not possible.  This returns all names in both tables, unless you have added other logic such as a `where` clause.